# Join two subqueries with ON or USING

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I have two queries I need to LEFT JOIN the first one with the second one. The purpose is to wrap all of this inside of something else bigger.  I got both the first and second queries working alone but cannot get them to join.

First Query:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM  (
    SELECT Source as system, DT as ts, Status as statusCode
    FROM (
      (SELECT 'SOURCE1' Source FROM Dual
       UNION SELECT 'SOURCE2' FROM Dual
       UNION SELECT 'SOURCE3' FROM Dual
       UNION SELECT 'SOURCE4' FROM Dual
       ) system
      CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            TO_DATE('09-30-2013','MM-DD-YYYY') - 1 + LEVEL dt
        FROM dual
            CONNECT BY
        LEVEL <= ( TO_DATE('10/05/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
                 - TO_DATE('09/30/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) + 1
       ) ts
       CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 'O' Status FROM Dual
        UNION SELECT 'C' FROM Dual
       ) statusCode
    )--For some reason cannot name this so need to wrap in another select *
  )Duals
```

Second Query:  (there would be a LEFT JOIN) between here

```
LEFT JOIN
```

Was tried

```
  Select * FROM(
    SELECT myTable1.system, TO_CHAR(maxResults.ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') as ts, myTable1.statusCode
    FROM (
      SELECT table_id, MAX(ts) as ts
         FROM myTable1_history
         WHERE ts BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-09-29','yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06','yyyy-mm-dd') 
         GROUP BY table_id )maxResults
    JOIN myTable1
    ON maxResults.table_id = myTable1.table_id
    WHERE myTable1.statusCode = 'C'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT myTable1.system as "system", TO_CHAR(myTable1.ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') as "ts", 'O' as "statusCode" 
    FROM myTable1
    WHERE myTable1.ts BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-09-29','yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06','yyyy-mm-dd') 
    --AND   myTable1.statusCode = 'O'
    )Records
```

and

```
USING (system, ts, statusCode)
```

I tried just sticking in a LEFT JOIN in the middle of the two queries but didn't work (I am probably doing it wrong) as shown

EDIT: Added the JOIN and USING as example of what was not working, receiving "invalid table name"

Comment: What do you need them to JOIN on?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't work' ?

Comment: @StevieG I put a LEFT JOIN in between and then a USING(system, ts, statusCode) at the end just gettin unhelpful error messages from SQL Developer

Comment: @Ben USING(system, ts, statusCode)

Comment: What unhelpful error messages are you getting?

Comment: @StevieG ORA-00903: invalid table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, assuming you want to join on all columns?

```
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT system, ts, statuscode
   FROM  (SELECT Source as system, DT as ts, Status as statusCode
                FROM ((SELECT 'SOURCE1' Source FROM Dual
                            UNION SELECT 'SOURCE2' FROM Dual
                            UNION SELECT 'SOURCE3' FROM Dual
                            UNION SELECT 'SOURCE4' FROM Dual
                 ) system CROSS JOIN (SELECT TO_DATE('09-30-2013','MM-DD-YYYY') - 1 + LEVEL dt
                                                                    FROM dual
                                                                CONNECT BY
                                                                    LEVEL <= ( TO_DATE('10/05/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
                                                                             - TO_DATE('09/30/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) + 1
                                                                       ) ts CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'O' Status FROM Dual
                                                                                                     UNION SELECT 'C' FROM Dual) statusCode
    )
  ))duals LEFT JOIN 
  (Select * FROM(
    SELECT myTable1.system, TO_CHAR(maxResults.ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') as ts, myTable1.statusCode
    FROM (
      SELECT table_id, MAX(ts) as ts
         FROM myTable1_history
         WHERE ts BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-09-29','yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06','yyyy-mm-dd') 
         GROUP BY table_id )maxResults
    JOIN myTable1
    ON maxResults.table_id = myTable1.table_id
    WHERE myTable1.statusCode = 'C'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT myTable1.system, TO_CHAR(myTable1.ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') as ts, 'O' as statusCode 
    FROM myTable1
    WHERE myTable1.ts BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-09-29','yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06','yyyy-mm-dd') 
    --AND   myTable1.statusCode = 'O'
    ) Records ON duals.system = records.system AND duals.ts = records.ts AND duals.statusCode = records.statusCode
```

Comment: Also worth noting, the last "UNION ALL" is naming the columns differently than the first part of it. You're naming "system" as "Source" and would not be able to join on it. Similarly with "timestamp" vs "ts" and "StatusCode" vs "Status". Make sure the column names are the same for anything you want to be joined.

Comment: As long as the data types are the same it'll be fine - the column names are irrelevant in a UNION ALL.

Comment: @mayabelle I think that was my fault, I did Find/Replace to protect our DB schema, forgot to update that

Comment: I am wondering if you aren't missing a couple closing parentheses